# What is "iCloudUserNotificationsd" app?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, icloud, notifications

After using Photos app for the first time on El Capitan, and importing photos from an iPhone, an app showed up on my Dock titled "iCloudUserNotificationsd" (yes with a 'd' on the end). The icon in the doc is the usual Apple logo for iCloud, a blue cloud on a white background.

This app stops me from shutting down the MacBook, with message:

> Your Mac hasn’t shut down because "iCloudUserNotificationsd" failed to quit. To continue shutting down, quit "iCloudUserNotificationsd".

I know the `d` usually refers to a daemon process, so I am surprised to see an app icon on the Dock.

➠ What is this process, why is it happening, and what should I do?

I am using iCloud for email & notes, but not documents nor photos.